# How to retrieve Test Cases associated with the Test Set

Tags: java, rally

I tried to run provided code for `jar 2.0.2` and now for `2.0.4` Both times received an error at line: `int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().size();`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array. at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:106) at GetTCofTS.main(GetTCofTS.java:50)
```

I can overcome this error (since it is really not an array that is coming back) , but it won't resolve my problem, that I am trying to get not only the number of TestCases associated with the current TestSet, but list of TestCases - at least their formatted ID. Is it a bag in Rally?

```
public class GetTCofTS {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";

    String username = "user@co.com";
    String password = "secret";

    String applicationName = "RESTExampleFindTestCasesOfTestSet";
    String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111";
    String projectRef = "/project/2222";
    String wsapiVersion = "1.43";


    RallyRestApi restApi = null;
    try {
        restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 

        QueryRequest testSetRequest = new QueryRequest("TestSet");
        testSetRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        testSetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] {"Name", "TestCases", "FormattedID"}));

        testSetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", "someTS"));

        QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testSetRequest);
        System.out.println("Successful: " + testSetQueryResponse.wasSuccessful());
        System.out.println("Size: " + testSetQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount());
        for (int i=0; i<testSetQueryResponse.getResults().size();i++){
            JsonObject testSetJsonObject = testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println("Name: " + testSetJsonObject.get("Name") + " ref: " + testSetJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString() + " Test Cases: " + testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases"));
            int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().size();
            System.out.println(numberOfTestCases);
            if(numberOfTestCases>0){
                  for (int j=0;j<numberOfTestCases;j++){
                  System.out.println(testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID"));
                 }
            }

        }

    } finally {
        if (restApi != null) {
            restApi.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This should work as long as the api version is 1.43.  In v2.0 collections are not returned in results and instead a count and a collection url are returned in an object.  Could it be that the wsapi version is not being set correctly?  I ran your code and did not get any errors...

Comment: Well, in example that provided by Rally, they suggest to use api version  "v2.0"
If I change my other piece of code to use "1.43", then it does not work. But this particular class does work with 1.43 and brings test cases number. Should not it be the same across all the code?

Comment: Did we get solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

v2.0 is the preferred version going forward.  The following small tweaks should get you up and going.

Instead of this (which works in 1.43 because the collection is returned):

```
int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().size();
if(numberOfTestCases>0) {
    for (int j=0;j<numberOfTestCases;j++) {
       System.out.println(testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID"));
    }
}
```

Do this:

```
//TestCases is an object with a Count and a ref to load the collection
int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("TestCases").get("Count").getAsInt();

if(numberOfTestCases > 0) {
    QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest(testSetJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("TestCases"));
    testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID"));
    //load the collection
    JsonArray testCases = restApi.query(testCaseRequest).getResults();
    for (int j=0;j<numberOfTestCases;j++){
        System.out.println(testCases.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID").getAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized that the returned collection of Test Cases is coming in wrong order. In my case I need to preserve the order of TestCases inside TestSet. I see the field "DragAndDropRank", but it is completely unreadable, something like this. " P!"zG~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " So how to return TestCases collection in the order that is displayed on the web?

Comment: Try testCaseRequest.setOrder('DragAndDropRank ASC');  The direction may also be DESC instead- not sure.

Comment: I tried this from the beginning, but the coming back order is again back on Formatted ID. I suspect it is a bug. Our QA automation is heavily relying on this order, so I am not sure how to proceed now. I have screen shots to show order in Rally and coming order from Java.

Comment: Can you submit a case with Rally Support with this information?  I was able to reproduce your problem and it seems like a valid defect in the WSAPI.