# unable to print test cases in a test set using rallyapi

Tags: rally

My idea was to update testcaseresults present in a test set.but i am not able to get test cases present in a testset.
 i was triyng to get into test set and get the test case where i can query for each of the test

RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "username", "pass");
        restApi.setApplicationName("CrudExample");

```
    QueryRequest testSetRequest = new QueryRequest("TestSet");
    testSetRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[]{"Name","TestCases","FormattedID"}));

    testSetRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TS346"));

    QueryResponse testSetQueryResponse = restApi.query(testSetRequest);

    if(testSetQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()){

    System.out.println("Successful: " + testSetQueryResponse.wasSuccessful());
    System.out.println("Size: " + testSetQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount());
    for (int i=0; i<testSetQueryResponse.getResults().size();i++){
        JsonObject testSetJsonObject = testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println("Name: " + testSetJsonObject.get("Name") + " ref: " + testSetJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString() + " Test Cases: " + testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonObject().get("_ref"));
       // int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().size();
        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest("https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestSet/15150807/TestCases");
        GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
        JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
       System.out.println(obj.getAsString());
        int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonObject().get("Count").getAsInt();
        System.out.println(numberOfTestCases);
        if(numberOfTestCases>0){
              for (int j=0;j<numberOfTestCases;j++){
                  System.out.println(testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID"));
             }
        }

    }
    }
        else {
            String[] createErrors;
            createErrors = testSetQueryResponse.getErrors();
            System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
            for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
            }
        }
```

output:

Successful: true
Size: 1
Name: "pre-acceptance automated regression" ref:rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testset/15150807667
Test Cases: "rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestSet/15150807667/TestCases

Comment: Never mind i found an older posted answered
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934895/how-to-retrieve-test-cases-associated-with-the-test-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
int numberOfTestCases = testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonObject().get("Count").getAsInt();
System.out.println(numberOfTestCases);
if(numberOfTestCases>0){
for (int j=0;j<numberOfTestCases;j++){
   System.out.println(testSetJsonObject.get("TestCases").getAsJsonArray().get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID"));
 }
```

Use this:

```
if(numberOfTestCases>0){
  QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest(testSetJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("TestCases"));
  testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] {"Name", "Results", "FormattedID"}));
  //load the collection
  JsonArray testCases = restApi.query(testCaseRequest).getResults();
  for (int j=0;j<numberOfTestCases;j++){
     System.out.println(testCases.get(j).getAsJsonObject().get("FormattedID").getAsString());
   }
}
```