# How to copy a test set with its test cases and maintain the original relative ranking of test cases within the test set

Tags: rally, pyral

I am trying to build an automation framework on Rally. I am using Rally RESTful API and Pyral. The ranking method of the workspace I am working in is DnD method. I am able to copy the test set and its test cases **but unable to maintain the original ranking of test cases within test set.**

I tried to GET the test cases of a specific test set with order = 'DragAndDropRank' but it only gives me the same order as FormattedID of the test case. Ex:

```
query_criteria = 'TestSets = "%s"' % str(ts._ref)
response = self.rally.get('TestCase', fetch=True, query=query_criteria, order='DragAndDropRank')    
for tc in response:    
....
```

Let's say there are three test cases TC1, TC2, TC3 within the test set TS1. In the "Iteration Test Case Status" view of Rally, the order of test cases in TS1 is: TC3, TC1, TC2. However, the order of tc generated from code above is always TC1, TC2, TC3.

**How can I get the original relative order of test cases within the test set in the "Iteration Test Case Status" view of Rally?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a defect that was first mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934895/how-to-retrieve-test-cases-associated-with-the-test-set/19968232?noredirect=1#comment30559582_19968232).
Unfortunately the defect is still open.

Comment: Thank you nickm. Can this issue be resolved by changing the ranking method from "DragAndDropRank" to "manual ranking"? Will the original ranking be reserved? I cannot try this on my project as it will affect the whole workspace and the admin does not allow it.

Comment: Switching ranking method for the entire workspace is a major change that has implications beyond this scenario. See https://help.rallydev.com/prioritizing-work to decide if it is worth it.